# Java IO Exception handling

Tags: java, exception

when I debug the below code, there is an `SmbException` and goes catch block line `sb.append(pLogger.reportError(pStr, e));`, but it does not go into the method `reportError()`.

what is the  reason behind this. please advise if any changes.

```
    try {
        sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
    } catch (SmbException e) {
       sb.append(pLogger.rError(pathStr, e));
    }
```

below is `rError()` method

```
public String rError(String pxString,Exception e){      

    String errorToMailStr=null;
    abcd="Verifying @ "+pxString+"::Error ["+e.getMessage()+"]";
    logger.debug("Error when verifying @ "+pxString+":Error ["+gMsg(e)+"]");
    return abcd;
}
```

at line `logger.debug("Issue "+pxString+":Error ["+gMsg(e)+"]");`

is going to below method and ends.

```
public abstract class ReflectiveCallable {
    public Object run() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return runReflectiveCall();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My first guess is that pathLogger isn't the class you think it is.

Comment: yes,pathLogger is class instance. I am able to call other methods in that class.

Comment: Try putting a call to reportError in the `try` range.

Comment: while debuging stop on line where `sb.append` is, and press F5 (eclipse), you will se where code goes then.

Comment: try range you mean in try block? I wanted to capture the error and log in different.

Comment: @Antoniossss, I did that, it is going the smbrelated exception and even  not triggering the reportError(). I put debug point at this method as well

Comment: So app did enter in `reportError` method?

Comment: sorry app did not enter in that method @Antoniossss

Comment: in these cases, should we really do in this way or should it mandatory to throw error and then process the error?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response

Comment: since it is my delivery code, I wanted to remove this post for security. is there any issue?

Comment: If you've got a security dependency on what you've posted above you're in deep yogurt.

Comment: @mahesh You can flag the post for moderator attention and ask them if they can delete it. **Don't** just blank the post (which some people do!) which is annoying and the code can still be viewed in old edit revisions.

Comment: Note that if the post has not met one of the conditions where you can't delete it yourself (I forget what they are) you can just delete it yourself if you really want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have revealed here, there is a problem in `getExceptionMsg()`

Comment: ya my bad, there was a small issue. it is working fine.